# EF-Core Single Deployment; Multiple Databases; Migrations

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I currently have a .net core web api that has a SQL Server database per client. An api key is required to be passed in for every call and then is looked up in a master tenant database to get the correct connection string. The api will then set the connection string in the startup file and run the call.

Within the api, I have an endpoint that allows me to update all tenants to the latest migration and I also have a console app that will do the same. Something like this:

```cs
public async Task UpdateAllDatabases()
{
    var qry = await GetAll(null, true);
    foreach (var i in qry)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MigrationContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(i.DatabaseConnectionString);
        using (var tenantContext = new MigrationContext(optionsBuilder.Options, _appSettings))
        {
            tenantContext.Database.Migrate();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is when I need to `remove-migration`. How can I remove a migration from all tenant databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same Migrate method but with the parameter ‘targetMigration’.

This will upgrade or rollback all databases to the specified target migration.

```
public void Migrate (string targetMigration = null);
```

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.imigrator.migrate)

**Update: added example**

*MigrationContext.cs*

```
public class MigrationContext : DbContext
{
}
```

*Execute migrations*

```
using (var tenantContext = new MigrationContext())
{
    tenantContext.Database.GetService<IMigrator>().Migrate("targetMigration");
}
```

*.csproj file*

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example because my `tenantContext.Database.Migrate();` does not have an overload for string.

Comment: Which version of .net core are you using? And which version of entity framework core?

Comment: Core 2.2 and EF Core 2.2.4 - Your solution is working. Thank-You!

Answer (score 0):

i'm resloved
[EFCoreMigrateMultiDatabase](https://github.com/xuejmnet/EFCoreMigrateMultiDatabase)
this is my demo,need replace service `IMigrationsScaffolder` and `IMigrationsAssembly` support different database with single dbcontext to migration

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).